# Sublime Text 3 can't find '__main__' module in ''

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, error-handling, sublimetext3

I just downloaded Sublime Text 3 for Mac and tried to run print("Hello world!") as a test by clicking on "build".

The output says

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't find '**main**' module in ''

and some other stuff.

I'm using Python 3 for several months now and I know the main differences between Python 2 and Python 3, but I have no idea what that output means.

Comment: You tried to run this *how*? Please be specific as to what steps you used.

Comment: You didn't save your Python file before you ran it; you have to manually save a new file at least once to give it a name on disk so that the external Python interpreter that gets executed by the build system can find it. (as an aside, the error diagnostic information that Sublime provides in the build output is very helpful in determining why a build might be going wrong; if you have build problems you should include everything and not just the error message from the external tool).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I also get the same problem in sublime text 3. And I am fixed.

1. Open command palette and install the install package.
2. After completed install python3.
3. And change like build system, syntax and others.
4. Finally try to print('hello world')
5. Save the file in .py extension is must otherwise you getting the same error